# TikZ Can I draw an arrow by specifying the initial point, direction, and length?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I would like to draw something similar to this:[image]

I was able to draw the triangles, but I cannot figure out how to easily draw the arrows. This is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-6, -3) -- (6, -3)  -- (-2, 3) -- cycle; % Left - Right - Top
\draw (-4,0) -- (2, 0); % Horizontal Bisector
\draw (0, -3) -- (-4,0); % Left Bisector
\draw(0,-3) -- (2,0); % Right Bisector
\draw [->] (0.5, 0.825) -- (-0.5, 1.575); % slope -3/4
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Calculating the length, direction, and position of each arrow would take me hours. Is there a way to specify an arrow by giving the initial point, length, and direction? If not, is there a different way to do this diagram? I am a beginner at TikZ (and LaTeX in general) so I am not necesarily looking so much for the absolute shortest solution, but more for a solution that I can understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a version that modifies the `to path`. So you need to replace `--` by `to`, and to apply the style, e.g.

```
\draw[pft] (-6, -3) to (0, -3) to (-4,0) to cycle;
```

The `to path` is modified in such a way that a sloped arrow (from the `shapes.arrows` library) is attached in the middle of the path. `allow upside down` is used to avoid that Ti*k*Z intelligently rotates the arrows in a way that is appropriate for texts. I also would use symbolic coordinates, and the nodes can be placed in the centers of the triangles with `barycentric cs:`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[pft/.style={to path={--(\tikztotarget)
    node[midway,above=0.6em,marrow,allow upside down]{}}},
    marrow/.style={sloped,fill, minimum height=3cm, single arrow, single arrow
    head extend=.5cm, single arrow head indent=.25cm,xscale=0.3,yscale=0.15}]
 \path (-6, -3) coordinate (A)  (6, -3) coordinate (B) (-2, 3) coordinate (C)
  (A) -- (B) coordinate[midway] (AB) (B) -- (C) coordinate[midway] (BC)         
  (C) -- (A) coordinate[midway] (CA);   
 \draw[pft] (A) to (AB) to (CA) to cycle
    (AB) to (B) to (BC) to cycle
    (CA) to (BC) to (C) to cycle
    (CA) to (AB) to (BC) to cycle;
 \path (barycentric cs:A=1,AB=1,CA=1) node{$T_1^{(1)}$}
  (barycentric cs:AB=1,BC=1,CA=1) node{$T_2^{(1)}$}
  (barycentric cs:CA=1,BC=1,C=1) node{$T_3^{(1)}$}
 (barycentric cs:B=1,AB=1,BC=1) node{$T_4^{(1)}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can use the the `show path construction` and the `markings` decoration to put an arrow next to every path segment.  The limitations are that you have to repeat the last point in the path (`-- cycle` alone won't do it) and you have to take care of the direction in which you draw the path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        parallel arrows/.style={
            postaction=decorate,
            decoration={
                show path construction,
                lineto code={
                    \path[
                        postaction=decorate,
                        decoration={
                            markings,
                            mark=at position .5 with {
                                \draw[red,-stealth] (-.5,.1) -- (.5,.1);
                            }
                        }
                    ] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    \draw[parallel arrows] (-6,-3) -- (0,-3) -- (-4,0) -- (-6,-3) -- cycle;
    \draw[parallel arrows] (0,-3) -- (6,-3) -- (2,0) -- (0,-3) -- cycle;
    \path[parallel arrows] (-4,0) -- (0,-3) -- (2,0) -- (-4,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[parallel arrows] (-4,0) -- (2,0) -- (-2,3) -- (-4,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]