# Illustrating the random forest algorithm in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, forest

I'm trying to illustrate the workings of a [random forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) in TikZ by combining these two figures. The TikZ picture should have the different tree structures present in the second image while also showing the path through each tree of a single sample (red dots) as shown in the first.

1. [source](http://www.nrronline.org/viewimage.asp?img=NeuralRegenRes_2018_13_6_962_233433_f2.jpg)
   [image]
2. [source](https://towardsdatascience.com/random-forests-and-decision-trees-from-scratch-in-python-3e4fa5ae4249)
   [image]

This is what I have so far.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} for tree={l sep=3em, s sep=3em, anchor=center, inner sep=0.7em, fill=blue!50, circle, font=\Large\sffamily}
  [Training Data, draw, rectangle, rounded corners, orange, text=white
    [,red!70[[][]][,red!70[[][]][,red!70[,red!70][]]]]
    [,red!70[,red!70[[][]][,red!70]][[][[][]]]]
    [,red!70[[][]][,red!70[,red!70[][,red!70]][]]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I'm still struggling with:

1. Drawing boxes around and numbering each tree (tree 1, tree 2, tree n) as in the second image.
2. Getting the 3 dots between trees 2 and n.
3. Drawing arrows along the path that a sample takes through each tree as in image 1.
4. Combining the results of all trees at the bottom with the text "majority voting for classification/mean for regression"

Any help with that would be much appreciated!

### Update

Thanks to user121799's awesome help, this is the finished TikZ image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\tikzset{
  font=\Large\sffamily\bfseries,
  red arrow/.style={
    midway,red,sloped,fill, minimum height=3cm, single arrow, single arrow head extend=.5cm, single arrow head indent=.25cm,xscale=0.3,yscale=0.15,
    allow upside down
  },
  black arrow/.style 2 args={-stealth, shorten >=#1, shorten <=#2},
  black arrow/.default={1mm}{1mm},
  tree box/.style={draw, rounded corners, inner sep=1em},
  node box/.style={white, draw=black, text=black, rectangle, rounded corners},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={l sep=3em, s sep=3em, anchor=center, inner sep=0.7em, fill=blue!50, circle, where level=2{no edge}{}}
  [
  Training Data, node box
  [sample and feature bagging, node box, alias=bagging, above=4em
  [,red!70,alias=a1[[,alias=a2][]][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[[][]][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[,red!70,edge label={node[below=1ex,red arrow]{}}][,alias=a3]]]]
  [,red!70,alias=b1[,red!70,edge label={node[below=1ex,red arrow]{}}[[,alias=b2][]][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}]][[][[][,alias=b3]]]]
  [~~$\dots$~,scale=2,no edge,fill=none,yshift=-4em]
  [,red!70,alias=c1[[,alias=c2][]][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[,alias=c3][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}]][,alias=c4]]]]
  ]
  \node[tree box, fit=(a1)(a2)(a3)](t1){};
  \node[tree box, fit=(b1)(b2)(b3)](t2){};
  \node[tree box, fit=(c1)(c2)(c3)(c4)](tn){};
  \node[below right=0.5em, inner sep=0pt] at (t1.north west) {Tree 1};
  \node[below right=0.5em, inner sep=0pt] at (t2.north west) {Tree 2};
  \node[below right=0.5em, inner sep=0pt] at (tn.north west) {Tree $n$};
  \path (t1.south west)--(tn.south east) node[midway,below=4em, node box] (mean) {mean in regression or majority vote in classification};
  \node[below=3em of mean, node box] (pred) {prediction};
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{4mm}] (bagging) -- (t1.north);
  \draw[black arrow] (bagging) -- (t2.north);
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{4mm}] (bagging) -- (tn.north);
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{5mm}] (t1.south) -- (mean);
  \draw[black arrow] (t2.south) -- (mean);
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{5mm}] (tn.south) -- (mean);
  \draw[black arrow] (mean) -- (pred);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following should do:

1. Use `fit`.
2. Add an appropriate node.
3. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499726/121799).
4. Add the nodes by hand.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{marrow/.style={midway,red,sloped,fill, minimum height=3cm, single arrow, single arrow
    head extend=.5cm, single arrow head indent=.25cm,xscale=0.3,yscale=0.15,
    allow upside down}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
for tree={l sep=3em, s sep=3em, anchor=center, inner sep=0.7em, fill=blue!50,
circle, font=\Large\sffamily,where level=1{no edge}{}}
  [Training Data, draw, rectangle, rounded corners, orange, text=white,alias=TD
    [,red!70,alias=a1[[,alias=a2][]][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,marrow]{}}[[][]][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,marrow]{}}[,red!70,edge label={node[below=1ex,marrow]{}}][,alias=a3]]]]
    [,red!70,alias=b1[,red!70,edge label={node[below=1ex,marrow]{}}[[,alias=b2][]][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,marrow]{}}]][[][[][,alias=b3]]]]
    [~$\cdots$~,scale=4,no edge,fill=none,yshift=-1em]
    [,red!70,alias=c1[[,alias=c2][]][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,marrow]{}}[,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,marrow]{}}[,alias=c3][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,marrow]{}}]][,alias=c4]]]
  ]
\node[draw,fit=(a1)(a2)(a3)](f1){};  
\node[draw,fit=(b1)(b2)(b3)](f2){};  
\node[draw,fit=(c1)(c2)(c3)(c4)](f3){};  
\path (f1.south west)--(f3.south east) node[midway,below=4em] (David) {mean};
\node[below=2em of David] (pred){prediction};
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}{\draw[-stealth] (TD) -- (f\X.north);
\draw[-stealth] (f\X.south) -- (David);}
\draw[-stealth] (David) -- (pred);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's great! The 4th item refers to what you see at the bottom of both images 1 and 2, the arrows combining the output of each tree into the strings "Majority vote" and "mean", resp. How would I achieve that?

Comment: @Casimir You could use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503730/121799), for instance. That is, add the nodes and draw the arrows. (see update)

Comment: One last thing, how to shorten the lines from "Training Data" to each tree such that they terminate just outside the fitted box and in an arrow head.

Comment: @user121799 The standalone file on its own compiles fine but trying to import it, I keep getting the error `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/single arrowhead extend', to which you passed '.5cm', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` even though I have `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,positioning,fit}` in my preamble. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: @Casimir It seems that a space gets suppressed, the key is `/tikz/single arrow head extend' and not `/tikz/single arrowhead extend'. Are you sure that you have a space between `arrow` and `head` in your file?

Comment: @user121799 Thank you so much! I literally spent 30 minutes trying to fix this! The problem was a line break between `arrow` and `head` which (like I said) didn't cause a problem in the standalone file but for some very odd reason was parsed away when importing in the main file. All's working now.